# Add a new field in mongoDB from another collection independently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections: **profiles** and **contents**

The **profiles** collection looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('618ef65e5295ba3132c11111'),
  blacklist: [ObjectId('618ef65e5295ba3132c33333'), ObjectId('618ef65e5295ba3132c22222')],
  //more fields
}
```

The **contents** collection looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('618ef65e5295ba3132c00000'),
  owner: ObjectId('618ef65e5295ba3132c22222'),
  //more fields
}
```

What I need is to get those *contents* where `owner` is not included in the `blacklist`. I thought about to put the **blacklist** field into the *contents* documents. I could get the profile by id separately (in another query) and set it manually in the aggregation where I get the contents, but this requires one extra connection.

So my question is: Is there a way to add **my profile** into each document of another collection? keep in mind that I have the profile ID.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question here is, you stated (what i believe is) a proper solution to your problem, query 1 fetch blacklist owners, query2 execute logic and exclude those from the blacklist.

What exactly is your issue with this approach?

Comment: My issue was to do all in the same aggregation. I 've just solved this by setting the profileId with a `set` stage and after do the lookup with one "fixed" value (profileId). Basically add the same ptofile document to all contents document

Comment: That's one way to do it but it adds overhead to the pipeline, why not just use it as a parameter when needed?

Comment: How am I supposed to do that? Keep in mind that I need to get only documents where their owner is not into my blacklist

Comment: I added some puesdo code to my answer below, i believe you're probably doing something similar, just with `$set` instead with adds overhead to the pipeline.

Comment: You should consider replacing the term `blacklist` - https://inclusivenaming.org/word-lists/tier-1/#whitelist-blacklist

Answer (score 1):

Here is some psuedo code on how it "should" look like, First fetching the blacklists owners, then using that variable as a parameter in the pipeline.

```
const profileId = input;
const blackListIds = await db.getCollection('profiles').distinct('blacklist', { _id: profileId });
const aggregationResults = await db.getCollection('contents').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            owner: {$nin: blackListIds}
        }
    }
    ... continuation of pipeline ...
])
```